# Unable to mount Encrypted drive

Tags: encryption

> Error starting job: Failed to execute child process "cryptsetup" (No such file or directory)

After a system reinstall (I'm on Ubuntu 10.04), I'm having trouble accessing my second Hard Disk, when I try to mount the encrypted volume I am prompted to enter the password, when I do I receive the above error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly open the terminal and type

> sudo apt-get install cryptsetup

Now retry mounting your encrypted drive.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that, just get "E: Couldn't find package cryptswap
" do you know what ppa it's in?

Comment: I think its 'cryptsetup' instead of 'cryptswap'.
Secondly you may try using :
"sudo apt-get update"
And then retry the above solution.

Comment: Could you please let me know what worked? Were you making a mistake in the name as 'cryptswap' or did the update help?

Comment: As a side-note, in order to tell what package a file is provided in, you can use `apt-file`.